# How to read HTML source from IFRAME using selinium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

```
System.out.println("iframe source::"+driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(1).getText());
```

I have tried the above code but it is returning empty.

`driver.getPageSource()` will return HTML code of all frames but I need the html content of current frame.

Comment: You can use `executeScript`:  `document.querySelectorAll('IFRAME')[0].contentDocument`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch to the iFrame first and then do a `driver.getPageSource()`.

```
WebElement iFrame = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(1);
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
driver.getPageSource();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

you're welcome

Comment: It is important to call `defaultContent()` before calling `frame()` again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on excellent response by Alok, the `driver.getPageSource();` gave me enough detail to navigate within the `i-Frame` using:

```
    WebElement iFrame = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(6); 
          driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
//        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
          System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='description']")).getText());

//To click button 'Ill Do this later' in the popup
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='deny']")).click();
          driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

//This is my (partial) getpageSource() output to create xpath: 
<div class=" webpush-prompt"><div class="wrapper"><div class="table content-table"><div class="tablerow"><div id="webpush-prompt" class="container tablecell"><div class="description-container"><div class="description">makemytrip.com wants to start sending you push notifications. Click <b>Allow</b> to subscribe.</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="button-group-custom clearfix"><button id="deny" class="button close">I'll do this later</button><button id="allow" class="button">Allow</button></div><div class="we-beak"></div></div></div></body></html>
```